# Not able to get last inserted ID from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, lastinsertid

I'm inserting multiple rows from one table to another, based on ID.
For this project I'm using PDO for all DB queries. This is the code / function I'm using:

```
  protected function importData($data) {
    $i = 0;

    $this->db->beginTransaction();

    foreach($data as $item) {
      $id = $item['id'];

      $sql .= "INSERT INTO table1 (name,age)
              SELECT name, age
              FROM table12
              WHERE id = $id; ";

      $this->db->exec($sql);   
      $i++;   
    }
    $this->db->commit();

    // None of these are working
    $last_id1 = $this->db->exec('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
    $last_id2 = $this->db->lastInsertId();

    echo 'id1: '.$last_id1.', id2:'.$last_id2;
  }
```

But for some resaon, I'm not able to get the last inserted ID.
If I try `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` in `Toad for MySQL`, I do get a result, but it's not the ID of the last inserted row.

Why isn't the last inserted row id registered when I insert rows this way?
Is it because I'm using `beginTransaction` and `commit` and therefore it is handled as one transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. You need to get the ID before you commit the transaction.